# Nillable element getting redundant data in output file when using ObjectFactory

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm creating a `JAXBElement<BigInteger>` element with an `ObjectFactory`.

The object is created with a `null` value, as the schema for this field indicates that it has a `nillable` attribute.

During the marshalling to xml, the output file shows:

```
<TaxCode xsi:nil="true"/>
```

How can I have it write `<taxCode/>` only?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because that would be wrong. `<taxCode/>` and `<TaxCode xsi:nil="true"/>` are not the same thing.

`<taxCode/>` means a `<taxcode>` element with blank but not-null content (i.e. an empty string), whereas `<TaxCode xsi:nil="true"/>` is explicitly saying `<taxCode>` is null.

Assuming that your `ObjectFactory` was generated by XJC from an XML Schema, then if JAXB were to produce `<taxCode/>` then it would be in violation of the schema.

If changing the schema is an option, then remove `nillable` from the element declaration, and regenerate the code. JAXB should then omit the `<taxCode/>` element altogether.

Comment: got it. I thought that Nillable means accepts a null value while it actually means empty value.